# How do you stop a rails server from the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, command-line, server

I had a weird incidence where I closed my terminal, but the server kept running. When I tried to run the server again I got a message that the server was still running. How could I stop the server through the command line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Way 1**: Just type: **Ctrl + C** in the terminal where your server is running.

**Way 2**: Another way of doing it:

In your terminal to find out the `PID` of the process:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

Then, kill the process:

```
$ kill -9 PID
```

**Way 3**: You can also use the following command to kill all running apps with `rails` in the name:

```
killall -9 rails
```

Comment: I know to use ctrl + c, but the window was already closed. Your second recommendation worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're most welcome. Glad it helped you solve your problem :-)

Comment: I had the issue where the server said it was already running and I had no way to Ctrl+C out of it. This helped, thanks!

Comment: For me, `killall rails` did not work, but `killall ruby` did.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal window, Ctrl + C will stop the server running.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the exact PID, rails usually saves it in `tmp/pids/server.pid` So you can stop the rails server using

```sh
kill -9  $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```